# How to pass data to controller method without specifying it in routes? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I have a method placeOrder which has some data. I need to pass this data to successOrder method. if Im doing this i should describe it in routes this way: `order-success/{id}` but I don't want to show it in url. Is it even possible and if yes then how?

```
placeOrder
    $this->successOrder($data['order_id']);
     return redirect()->route('successOrder');

successOrder($id)
    $this->template = env('THEME') . '.order_Success';
            $content = view(env('THEME') . '.order_Success_content')->with(['order_id' => $orderID])->render();
            $this->vars = array_add($this->vars, 'content', $content);
            return $this->RenderOutput();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass that data into input like this:

```
Request::input('id');
```

Then return view of your successOrder method

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this problem by doing this:

```
placeOrder
session()->put('order_ID', $data['order_id']);

successOrder
session()->get('order_ID')
```

If someone knows better and cleaner solution for this, please write it in comments (: